# When i run the build in Jenkins i got this Error : Cannot find firefox binary in PATH. Make sure firefox is installed

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, automated-tests, cucumber

I created a job Maven Project in Jenkins for the purpose to Compile and execute all my automatic tests, but when i build the job i got this error :

[image]

i got the same message error for all the scenarios

should i create a pipeline in place of project maven ?

i recupare my project with the link ssh GitLab and im working behind a proxy

Thnaks(y)

Comment: Jenkins/Jenkins node linux machine where you are running your tests has probably no Firefox - install it. Or you can use docker integrate it with Jenkins and use prepared image https://github.com/elgalu/docker-selenium/blob/master/README.md

Comment: how can i do to install/add firefox to the node linux machine ? thanks for your answer

Comment: I'm sorry it's out of SO scope - try to find some tutorials which fits your requirements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `docker-compose` file that will open 7 instances of FF and 1 instance on chrome. I use it with azure pipeline but you can integrate it with jenkins. You'll will have to add a jenkins task that runs `docker-compose`

To try on command line , just install docker desktop ( i use it with mac) and run below command

docker-compose -f /path/of/file  up

```
version: "3"
services:
  selenium-hub:
    image: selenium/hub:3.141.59-20210607
    container_name: selenium-hub
    ports:
      - "65299:4444"

  chrome:
    image: selenium/node-chrome:3.141.59-20210607
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - HUB_HOST=selenium-hub
      - HUB_PORT=4444


  firefox:
    image: selenium/node-firefox:3.141.59-20210607
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - HUB_HOST=selenium-hub
      - HUB_PORT=4444
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 7
```

For using `docker-compose` with azure pipeline , I am using the below.
Make sure you have `dockerRegistryEndpoint` setup (in below ex: Dockerhub) . I use this to run my cucumber tests and integrate third party cucumber report (`PublishCucumberReport@1`)in pipeline

```
trigger:
- master
resources:
- repo: self
variables:
  tag: '$(Build.BuildId)'
stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build and Push image
  jobs:
   - job: Build
     displayName: Build and Push
     pool:
        vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
     steps:
     - task: DockerCompose@0
       displayName: open browser instances
       inputs:
         containerregistrytype: 'Container Registry'
         dockerRegistryEndpoint: Dockerhub
         dockerComposeFile: '**/docker-compose.yml'
         action: 'Run a Docker Compose command'
         dockerComposeCommand: 'up -d'
         detached: true

     - task: Maven@3
       inputs:
         mavenPomFile: 'pom.xml'
         mavenOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
         jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
         publishJUnitResults: true
         testResultsFiles: '**/target/cucumber.html'
         goals: 'clean verify -P acceptanceTests -e -X'
         
     - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
       displayName: Publish cucumber report
       inputs:
         pathToPublish: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/s/target/cucumber-report/
         artifactName: 'cucumber.html'

     - task: PublishCucumberReport@1
       inputs:
         jsonDir: ./target/cucumber-report/
         outputPath: ./target/
```

For documentation , refer - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/docker-compose?view=azure-devops

Comment: Can you tell please how can i do integrating docker in Jenkiçns and also the azure pipeline?, if you're not able to do that please share with me a link explaining that in details , thanks for your answer

Comment: I edited above for azure pipeline.   Please  upvote/accept if it helped.